# Out[x] not the same as assigned expression

Tags: output-formatting, assignment, output

There seems to be a difference in the way Mathematica assigns a value to a variable and the way it assigns a value to the next *Out* object. I don't understand why this is happening.

For instance, take the following command:

```
In[1]=

          Pi // MatrixForm

Out[1]//MatrixForm=

          Pi
```

Why does the console say "*Out[1] // **MatrixForm***"? I would have expected *Mathematica* to evaluate the entire line of input and assign the value to the *Out[1]* object. Instead, it seems to have ignored the *MatrixForm* command and instead apply it to the output that was printed.

Let me *explicitly* assign a variable this value (as opposed to implicitly assigning the value to *Out*):

```
In[2]=

          m = Pi // MatrixForm

Out[2]//MatrixForm=

          Pi
```

Now if I look at the difference between *Out[2]* and *m*:

```
In[3]=

          m // FullForm
          Out[2] //FullForm

Out[3]//FullForm=

          MatrixForm[Pi]

Out[4]//FullForm=

          Pi
```

I had assumed that *Mathematica* would assign the *Out* object the exact same value as the *m* object but this does not appear to be the case. What is the explanation for this? How is *Out* treated differently, and why?